# httpd (Apache) のTLS1.1を無効化したい

Tags: linux, centos, apache, ssl

大変お世話になっております。

httpd (Apache) のTLS1.1を無効化したいために、以下の様に所定箇所を変更しているのですが、その下にあるssltestの結果の様に全くtls1.1が無効化されません。なぜ無効化されないのか、そしてこの様な場合どうすれば良いか何か手掛かりをお教え願いませんでしょうか？

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf**

```
SSLProtocol　-all  +TLSV1.2
```

**デーモンを再起動**

```
# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

`SSLProtocol +TLSV1.2` の設定も試しましたが結果は同じでした。

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html で結果を確認。

```
Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 No
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No
```

PHP： 5.3.3
OS: ‪CentOS 6.9

Comment: httpdのエラーログ・アクセスログは確認しましたか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーログは確認しましたか？ 例えば質問文の

> ```
> SSLProtocol　-all  +TLSV1.2
> ```

ここには全角空白が含まれています。設定に関するエラーが出力されているかもしれません。

アクセスログは確認しましたか？ ssllabsで確認されているようですが、ssllabsからのアクセスがあり応答している形跡はありますか？ 設定を行っているサーバーと接続確認を行っているサーバーが一致していない可能性もあります。

Comment: sayuri様、cubic様、

全くその通りでございました。大変失礼いたしました。このスペースを全角と見抜くのは凄いです。お時間を頂きましてありがとうございます。また、スルーしたつもりはなく、かなりの数のログがあり、全てを一つ一つ調べていましたので時間がかかりました。即答できず申し訳ございませんでした。

Comment: @baseballjapan 確認中とは知らず失礼しました。